# Is it easy to port firefox OS apps to ubuntu touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm curious if Firefox OS apps will be possible to use in Ubuntu touch? Will Ubuntu touch have a firefox browser anytime soon? (Seems like the default is webkit at the moment.) Does web apps as first class citizen imply that a web app based OS will be easy to port to ubuntu touch? It's apparently really easy to install these apps in OSX, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: CSS and Javascript apps might not work, but some might - compare `Programmed In` for [Firefox OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_OS) & [Ubuntu Touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Touch). The problem is, the programs may require different [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Api)'s to what is available on each OS, meaning that the apps may not have the correct resources to function - imagine trying to make a cup to tea with no water...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FirefoxOS apps per se will not work on Ubuntu as the APIs are different. However, as *wilf* so kindly pointed out above, IF the app is CSS or Javascript it ***might*** work.

> Will Ubuntu Touch have a Firefox browser anytime soon?

That's up to Firefox: Send them a tweet at @MozPDX and ask.

Comment: How can you have a pure CSS app?

Answer (score 2):

The html version of my app IqFitFun has almost identical code base on Firefox Os, Ubuntu Touch/Ubuntu Desktop, IOS, Tizen, Windows8, Chrome OS, Facebook and Amazon WebApp. For Android I have a native implementation and for Windows Phone 8 the html version needs extra native code to integrate Web control. Even WebGL works fine, if you have a fallback for platform w/o support.
If you need In App Purchasing or gaming community integration, you definitely need different implementations. Same applies to all other platform dependent APIs.